# Are there best practices for working with static members in PHP?

Tags: php, static

PHP allows use of static member functions and variables, since 5.3 including late static bindings:

```
class StaticClass {
    public static $staticVar;

    ...
}

$o = new StaticClass();
```

Currently, there are various options to access those static members:

```
$o->staticVar;  // as instance variable/ function
$o::staticVar;  // as class variable/ function
```

Other options exist for accessing members from inside the class:

```
self::$staticVar;   // explicitly showing static usage of variable/ function
static::$staticVar; // allowing late static binding
```

Restructuring some existing classes that make some use of static members I've asked myself if there are best practices for working with static members in PHP?

Comment: Don't use `$o->staticVar;` to access static properties as it will give warnings these days; use `StaticClass::staticVar;` from outside the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, obviously, they all do different things.

```
$o->staticVar
```

This is **invalid**, since you cannot/should not access *static* properties with the instance property syntax.

```
StaticClass::$staticVar
```

This very plainly accesses a specific static variable on a very specific class.

```
$o::$staticVar
```

This accesses the static variable on the class that `$o` is an instance of. It's mostly used as a shorthand for the previous method and is equivalent in all respects. Obviously though, which class is used exactly depends on what class `$o` is an instance of.

```
self::$staticVar
```

This can be used only inside a class, and will always refer to the class that it's written in. It's a good idea to use this inside a class instead of `StaticClass::$staticVar` if the class refers to itself, since you don't need to worry about anything if you change the class name later. E.g.:

```
class Foo {

    protected static $bar = 42;

    public function baz() {
        self::$bar;  // good
        Foo::$bar    // the same, but should be avoided because it repeats the class name
    }

}
```

```
static::$staticVar
```

This can also only be used inside a class and is basically the same as `self` above, but resolves with late static binding and may hence refer to a child class.

What the "best practice" is is debatable. I'd say you should always be as specific as necessary, but no more. `$o::$staticVar` and `static::$staticVar` both allow the class to vary through child classes, while `self::$staticVar` and `StaticClass::$staticVar` do not. Following the [*open/closed principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID), it's a good idea to use the former, more variable method to allow for extensions.

Properties, both static and non-static, should also not be `public` to not break encapsulation.

Also see [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/).

Comment: At least this isn't allowed in PHP although it should invoke a static method on a member variable: $this->interpreter::staticMethod()

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use $this->staticVar. I am unsure when this changed (I believe PHP 5.4), but in recent versions it is no longer possible to retrieve static variables this way.

As for using late static binding, don't use it if you don't need it. The reason to use it would be if you plan to use inheritance and expect to change the value of the static variable in a derived class.